# Composition of Two Functions - Vector-Valued and Scalar-Valued

Tags: calculus, vectors

I have the following problem: $f(x, y) = x e^{x^2 + y^2}$, $c(t) = (t, −t)$, and I need to find $(f \circ c)'(t)$.

What I did was take the derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$, and I got the following gradient: $Df(x,y)=[2(x^2+1)(e^{x^2 + y^2}), 2xye^{x^2 + y^2}]$

I then took $c'(t)$ and got $[1, -1]$ (but as a vertical matrix, I don't know how to type that on here).

I substituted $x=1$, $y=-1$ and got $e^2$, but my grading program says it isn't correct. Can someone help me figure out where I might have gone astray?

Comment: A negative times a negative is a positive for 2xy for x=1, y=-1 is -2 and you multiply the second entry by negative one so you get a positive and should get about five e squared I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do multivariate chain rule, just compose the functions together first to get a standard scalar function, then differentiate afterwards:
$$
(f \circ c)(t) = f(t, -t) = te^{t^2 + (-t)^2} = te^{2t^2} \implies (f \circ c)'(t) = 4t^2 e^{2 t^2} + e^{2 t^2}
$$

Otherwise, if you want to use multivariate chain rule, then let $g(t) = (f \circ c)(t) = f(x(t), y(t))$ and observe that:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dg}{dt}
&= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt} \\
&= (2 x^2e^{x^2 + y^2} + e^{x^2 + y^2})(1) + (2xye^{x^2 + y^2})(-1) \\
&= (2 t^2e^{t^2 + (-t)^2} + e^{t^2 + (-t)^2}) - (2t(-t)e^{t^2 + (-t)^2}) \\
&= (2t^2e^{2t^2} + e^{2t^2}) + (2t^2e^{2t^2}) \\
&= 4t^2e^{2t^2} + e^{2t^2} \\
\end{align*}